# How to get original file path of file being uploaded, in PHP?

Tags: php

I know after you submit a form in PHP, `$_FILES['file']['tmp_name']` contains the temporary file path (if `name="file[]"` arbitrarily) but how to get full path of that file before it is uploaded, which may not even be inside server root folder?

Don't say the answer is `$_FILES['file']['tmp_name']` because that's not it.

Comment: You cannot and should not be able to.

Comment: if you could i would move all my files to `/kill/the/president/` directory before uploading

Answer (score 0):

You can't.

You could use `var_dump($file)` to see all the info you can get, and you won't see the original path there.